# Upgrade to 15.10 failed. Cannot login

Tags: upgrade

I tried upgrading from 14.04 to 15.10. It stalled with some prompt, and
when I pressed CTRL-C, the screen went black and the computer rebooted, but
was only able to boot until terminal mode since kernels would not load.

I did some diagnostics, and now it will boot into login screen, but 
freezes and I cannot login.  I would like to recover my files and do a
fresh install of ubuntu, but don't know how to find my files.

I cannot boot into recovery mode. I can boot with cd drive, but cannot find my files.   When I try "System
Monitor", it gives me only:
`/dev/sr0` `/cdrom` `/dev/loop/rofs` which is type squash.

Am I missing some permissions needed? Any ideas about how to find the files on the hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

Modified from: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery

- Boot the Ubuntu Live CD.
- Press Ctrl-Alt-F1

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt       
  sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev       
  sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc       
  sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys       
  sudo chroot /mnt     
  apt-get dist-upgrade           
  # If that fails do the following       
  apt-get update           
  apt-get upgrade
  ```

You may get and error saying that you need to run `dpkg-reconfigure --all` Do it. Broken installations can be fixed with `apt-get -f install`. If this solution works for you, after you reboot without the LiveCD do a `sudo update-grub` in a terminal to make sure your updated kernel gets loaded on boot.

If you have trouble accessing your network after chroot, you probably use DHCP and can work around this by adding OpenDNS name servers to your `/etc/resolv.conf` after you use chroot:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

Comment: OK, tried this, but after I did mount /dev/sda1 /mnt, command sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev returned response "mount point /mnt/dev does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

Resolved problem by repairing grub using:

http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

After I followed these instructions, I could boot into an earlier version
of linux and found my files.   Thanks for suggestions.